# Haskell, returning a char nth times

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to make a function in haskell using recursion that takes two arguments.
The function takes a char and an integer and will return the char n th times depending on the integer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a coding service. You should post your best attempt at solving this, and ask about specific issues you met. Asking others to write the code from scratch for you will only lead to the question being closed. Start by 1) writing the type for your function, 2) defining the base case (n=0), 3) defining the inductive case.

Comment: [First result from Hoogle after transcribing your "take a char and an integer and return the char n times" to `Char -> Integer -> [Char]`.](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Integer+-%3E+%5BChar%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, a function is a map from one type to another and from one value to another. Lists and `Data.Map` are also maps, just like functions. This means that you can enumerate all the possible cases to define your function. Let's do this and see if a pattern emerges:

```
rep :: Char -> Int -> [Char]
rep x 0 = []  --Something repeated zero times is an empty list
rep x 1 = [x]  --Something repeated one time is a list with one entry
rep x 2 = [x, x]
rep x 3 = [x, x, x]
rep x 4 = [x, x, x, x]
```

See the pattern?

```
rep x 0 = []
rep x n = x : (rep x $ n - 1)
```

Aaaand this is your function!

Note that this applies to any type, not only `Char`, so we can change the type signature:

```
rep :: a -> Int -> [a]
```

What if `n < 0`? Right now, Haskell will enter an infinite loop attempting to do:

```
x : (x : (x : (x : (...))))
```

How do we fix that? You can just return an empty list, for example:

```
rep x n = if n <= 0 then [] else x : (rep x $ n - 1)
```

Comment: @Oscar That belongs in a separate question, but you need to supply your attempt first and explain where you're stuck, because this site isn't a code writing service.